# How to make custom authentication on Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel application, with a login form. I am using subdomains, for example: {{business_subdomain}}.laravel.test. The purpose of my application is create companies in my database, and make registered users login on their attached company and specific domain.

So in my web.php I declared the following:

`Route::domain('{business_subdomain}.' . env('APP_URL'))->middleware(['business.subdomain'])->group(function ()`

My database contains the following tables:
* Standard tables like users
* Businesses which contains id, name and subdomain
* Business_user which contains business_id and user_id

The business_id (business_user table) has a relationship with id (business table)
The user_id (business_user table) has a relationship with id (users table)

I created a middleware that checks the following:

`$business = $request->user()->businesses->where('subdomain', $request->route('business_subdomain'))->first();`

So the subdomain value (business table) must be the equal to the URL/route subdomain value, otherwise when you login, you will get an 403 page.

So what I want to achieve: When a user **has** an account, but is not attached to the **right** company/business, I want to display the standard authentication error: These credentials do not match our records.

I've tried to use the code in my middleware on the LoginController and override almost every function separately, but it didn't work.

Do I need to override Laravel authentication functions, do I need to create another middleware or use Guards?

The laravel authentication login order (the order the application uses for logging in a user) seems very confusing for me.

Maybe someone can provide me with more information or help me out!

I tried to use the code in my middleware on the LoginController and override almost every function separately, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be looking for multi-tenancy. There are a couple different packages available, both for single and multi-database setups.

Here are [some very informative slides on the topic](https://tomschlick.com/2017/07/25/laracon-2017-multi-tenancy-talk/), specific to Laravel. And [an excellent article](https://ollieread.com/blog/2018/08/06/laravel-multi-tenancy-avoiding-over-engineering) for more detail.

We have a similar application with subdomain routing using [`torzer/awesome-landlord`](https://github.com/torzer/awesome-landlord). The tenant package ensures that login will only search for users of the correct tenant.

To set the correct tenant we added a middleware (`App` is the tenant, in your case it would be `Business`):

```php
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $subdomain = $this->getSubdomain($request->server('HTTP_HOST'));

        if ($subdomain) {
            $app = App::getBySlug($subdomain);

            abort_if(!$app, 404);

            $this->tenantManager->addTenant($app);
        } else {
            // empty or generic subdomain
            // this is OK as long as there is no user

            if ($user = $request->user()) {
                return $this->redirectToUserAppSubdomain($request, $user);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your really helpfull answer! But on which route do I need to provide this middleware, and how do I display the error on the login form when trying to log in with an account that is not in the company of the domain? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The middleware has to run on **all** requests. The package appends `WHERE business_id = CURRENT_BUSINESS` (`CURRENT_BUSINESS` is defined by `addTenant()`) to each select query of a model that belongs to a tenant (e.g. users). So the login form will automatically only look for users matching the email **in the current app** so it will fail if the entered email is in the wrong subdomain and show Laravel's default "user not found" error. Hope that's clear.